# How can I create a FIAT credit directly from a bank account?

Tags: accounts

How can I create a FIAT credit from a bank account for example from a Deutsche Bank account in Stellar

Thank

Comment: More precisely, is it possible to associate a Deutsche Bank account with a Stellar account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create "tokenize" FIAT being an issuer. For this, you must became a anchor, but not from you wallet directly.